# A Simple Unix Filter in Racket - Learning the Racket Way

Tags: scheme, racket

I've written the following simple filter in Racket as my first Racket program and am wondering if I am writing it in an "idiomatic Racket style".

```scm
#! /usr/bin/env racket
#lang racket

(require racket/cmdline)

(define a-prolog-mode? (make-parameter #f))

;; parses the options passed on the command-line
(command-line
 #:program "patoms"
 #:once-any
 [("-a" "--aprolog") "output as A-Prolog code"
                     (a-prolog-mode? #t)])

;; dlv-input? : string -> boolean
;; Returns True if the given text corresponds to the output of DLV
;; and False otherwise. DLV's output is prefixed by one of the following
;; strings: "DLV", "{", or "Best model".
(define (dlv-input? text)
  (regexp-match? #rx"^DLV|^{|^Best model" text))

;; text->answer-sets : string -> list of strings
;; Returns a list comprised of all of the answer sets in the given text.
(define (text->answer-sets text)
  (cond
    [(dlv-input? text) (regexp-match* #rx"{(.*?)}" text #:match-select cadr)]
    [else null]))

;; write-as-code : string
;; Writes the given answer set in plain text form to standard output.
(define (write-as-text answer-set)
  (let ([literals (map string-trim (string-split answer-set ","))])
    (cond
      [(empty? literals) (printf "~a~n" "{}")]
      [else (for-each (λ (literal) (printf "~a~n" literal)) literals)])
    (printf "~a~n" "::endmodel")))

;; write-as-code : string
;; Writes the given answer set as A-Prolog code to standard output.
(define (write-as-code answer-set)
  (let ([literals (map string-trim (string-split answer-set ","))])
    (for-each (λ (literal) (printf "~a.~n" literal)) literals)
    (printf "~a~n" "%%endmodel")))

;; main
;; Serves as the main function of the program. If a-prolog-mode is specified
;; by the user via the command-line, all of the answer sets that may be parsed
;; from standard input are written to standard output as A-Prolog. Otherwise
;; the answer sets are written in a plain text format.
(define (main)
  (let* ([text (port->string (current-input-port))]
         [answer-sets (text->answer-sets text)])
    (cond
      [(a-prolog-mode?) (for-each write-as-code answer-sets)]
      [else (for-each write-as-code answer-sets)])))

(main)
```

In general, any and all feedback would be very much appreciated given that this is my first foray into Racket.

Thank you kindly in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, this is very pleasant code to review.  Especially given you're new to the language.  Your function names are follow convention such as the use of ending predicates with `?` and indicating conversions with `->`.  The comments make this code easy to understand.  So bravo, keep at it!  That being said, here are some pretty minor suggestions.

1. ["Favor define when feasible"](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/Style/style/Choosing_the_Right_Construct.html#%28part._.Definitions%29).  Your `let`'s and `let*`'s could be changed to internal `define`'s to decrease nesting.
2. Change `(define (main) ...)` to [`(module+ main ...)`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._main-and-test%29).  Submodule support added in June's 5.3 release make having main's and test's easier than ever.
3. Within `main`, should one of the `cond` branches be using `write-as-text` instead of `write-as-code`?  right now, both branches do the same thing.  Along the same vein, the comment above `write-as-text` was copied but not changed from `;; write-as-code`.
4. In racket, we have 3 ways of doing output, display, write, and print.  Since your `write-as-text/code` functions use printing, I would change the names of those functions to be called `print-as-text/code`

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I have one more question - would it be better (or more idiomatic) to have a function which returns the appropriate writer (write-as-code or write-as-text) depending on the value of a-prolog-mode? This would seem to enable me eliminate the cond in the main module, but may increase some complexity. Is there a good rule of thumb regarding this?

Comment: Having a function like `(define (write-answer-set answer-set) ((if (a-prolog-mode?) write-as-code write-as-text) answer-set))` isn't a bad idea.  Modules that define parameters often have helper functions that consult their defined parameter to "do the right thing" so that you don't have to.